# How to correctly determine the stopping distance of a coasting bicycle when considering aerodynamic drag?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag

Given values of $C_{rr}$, $C_{d}{A}$ and $\rho$(Air density) how can I correctly determine the distance and time taken to coast from some $\upsilon$1 to $\upsilon$2?

Comment: I would like to note that this is not a homework question for what it's worth. I am able to determine the time and distance if only static friction and rolling resistance are factors, but am unsure of how to reconcile air resistance correctly. Alternatively, can anyone suggest a venue where a question like this will be more welcomed?

Comment: Homework tag does not imply that your question will be closed nor does it imply that the question is off-topic.

Comment: Hi bsdunx : See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your rolling resistance is independent of velocity, and that the force of rolling friction is $f_{rr} = -mgC_{rr}$, you can write the equation of motion as

$$F = m \frac{dv}{dt} =  - \left(m g C_{rr} +\frac12 \rho v^2 C_d A\right)$$

From [Wolfram Alpha we learn](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+dx%2Fdt+%3D+-(a+%2B+bx%5E2)) that the solution for

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = -\left(a + b v^2\right)$$

is

$$v(t) = -\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} \tan\left(\sqrt{ab} (c_1 + t)\right)$$

You need to think about this a little bit to understand that the situation where you are decelerating happens then $c_1+t<0$. Getting the values of $a$ and $b$ right:

$$\begin{align} a&= gC_{rr}\\
b&= \frac{\rho C_dA}{2m}\end{align}$$

The result is

$$v(t) = -\sqrt{\frac{2mgC_{rr}}{\rho C_d A}}\tan\left(\sqrt{\frac{\rho C_d A ~g C_{rr}}{2m}}\left(c_1+t\right)\right)$$

You find the integration constant $c_1$ from the initial velocity (put $t=0$; you will find that $c_1$ must be negative), and the evolution of velocity with time follows. Interestingly, there is a finite time to come to a complete stop. That doesn't happen when you have "pure" quadratic drag - it's the rolling friction that dominates at low speeds.

### Update

Just to check that things work as expected, I wrote a quick Python program that computes the velocity according to the above expression, incorporating also the effect of slope (note - if the slope is such that the object would accelerate, you get a "math domain error". This is not a hard thing to fix, but it would make the code more complicated to read, so I left that out for now.)

Running the code with three values of slope (where negative slope = downhill) gave the following plot; you can see that the slope of -5° almost exactly cancels the rolling resistance of 0.1 (arcsin(0.1) = 5.7°), leaving just the quadratic drag; if you set the quadratic drag coefficient $C_ad$ to zero, the velocity ends up almost completely unchanged. So yes, this is believable.

[image]

And the code (this is not meant to show "good Python", just something I threw together for a quick demo):

```
# rolling resistance and quadratic drag
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# pick some values for mass etc:
# these have obvious meanings, and SI units
m = 1.
g = 9.81
crr = 0.1
cda = 0.05
rho = 1.2
v0 = 10.

# convert to numbers we use in the formula
b = rho*cda/(2*m)

# a function that allows me to use degrees for slope:
def sind(theta):
    return math.sin(theta*math.pi/180.)

def vt(t,a,b,c1):
# implement the expression I derived
    temp = -np.sqrt(a/b)*np.tan(np.sqrt(a*b)*(c1+t))
# if velocity goes negative, things go awry
    stop = np.where(temp<0)
    if np.prod(np.size(stop))>0:
        # set all elements past the point where v first goes negative to zero
        temp[stop[0][0]:]=0
    return temp

# range of time for simulation:
t = np.linspace(0, 15, 500)

plt.figure()

# calculate for a range of slopes
for slope in np.arange(-5,6,5): 
  a = g*(crr + sind(slope))
  c1 = math.atan(-v0*math.sqrt(b/a))/math.sqrt(a*b)
  plt.plot(t, vt(t,a,b,c1), label='slope = %d'%slope)

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('velocity (m/s)')
plt.title('coasting down with rolling and quadratic friction')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Indeed the assumption of quadratic drag is one of the deficiencies I wanted to avoid. I assume to account for grade of slope I simply substitute \begin{align} b&= \frac{\rho C_dA}{2m\sin(\arctan G)}\end{align}

Comment: It occurred to me after writing this that the form of the equations is basically the same as for free fall with drag - which means that you can use those solutions to guide you as well (use the part of the trajectory where gravity opposes the motion, and scale it to give rolling resistance).

Comment: I think the grade would go into $a$, not $b$ - since that is not a velocity-dependent term. Let me think about that for a bit and update my answer.

Comment: The additional update has cleared up my misconceptions, I believe I have a working understanding of the factors involved now, regards.

Comment: @Floris I'm using your example to help me model the physics for an indoor bicycle training app and I would like to model slopes up to -10% and Crr of 0.0682. But this falls into the "Math Domain Error" due to the value of a being -ve and throws off the SQRT. Ideally, would like to get the model to work such that I can model the bicycle coasting down the hill (up to -10% slope), reaches terminal velocity and then either continues to freewheel down or add power to the equation (basically, start cycling) and get speeds above terminal velocity.

Comment: If the rolling resistance force is greater then the downhill component of gravitational force ($mg \sin\theta$), the bike will come to a halt. I suspect that’s why you are getting math domain errors.

Comment: @Floris Yeah That makes sense. However when I changed Crr from 0.1 to 0.0025, I still get the same error. (-10% Slope). Using the same conditions here https://bit.ly/2LOiIfV tells me that, freewheeling would get me to speed of 156kmh (rolling resistance is 1.46N). I'm lost

Comment: @myjunk Hm. I may have some time to try those boundary conditions and see what I come up with. A bug in my code (or yours...) or an error in the equations is always a possibility. I’ll get back to you.

Comment: @Floris I truly appreciate any/all help. I've been at this for nearly a week now scouring Google/Physics and even reading science literature trying to figure out how to model downhill speed at (future) time (t) so that I can implement some physics into my Cycling Training App when riding a virtual real world route. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The time it takes to go from $v_1$ to $v_2$ under the influence of $a(v)$ is 
$$ \Delta t= \int \limits_{v_1}^{v_2} \frac{1}{a}\,{\rm d}v $$

In your case the acceleration has the form $a(v) = -a_0 - a_2 v^2$, and we consider the time from $v_1$ to *any* other $v$

$$ t(v) = \int \limits_{v_1}^v -\frac{1}{a_0 + a_2 v^2} {\rm d}v = \frac{ \arctan\left( \sqrt{\frac{a_2}{a_0}} v_1 \right) - \arctan\left( \sqrt{\frac{a_2}{a_0}} v \right) }{\sqrt{a_0 a_2}} $$

Invert the above for

$$ v(t)  = \sqrt{\frac{a_0}{a_2}} \tan\left(\arctan\left( \sqrt{\frac{a_2}{a_0}} v_1 \right) -\sqrt{a_0 a_2}\; t \right) $$

---

The distance traveled over the same speed span is

$$ \Delta x = \int \limits_{v_1}^{v_2} \frac{v}{a}\,{\rm d}v$$

$$ x(v) = - \frac{1}{a_2} \ln \left( \frac{a_0+a_2 v^2}{a_0+a_2 v_1^2} \right) $$